# Why is the QT GUI affecting flowgraph performance so much?

Tags: qt, gnuradio, gnuradio-companion

When I change the flowgraph options of the `rx_ofdm.grc` example shipped with gnuradio from `No GUI` to `QT GUI` and leave `run=True`, the flowgraph in its default configuration (10 k Samples/s) causes 100% CPU load on one core. Even with 1 k Samples/s (which is like nothing for a modern CPU), this improves only slightly.

When I set `run=False` in the options dialog, the processor load vanishes completely. Now, I am wondering what is happening there and how I can improve the performance when using the QT GUI. Obviously, for some things I would really like to have the GUI :)

If it is somehow helpful to answering that question: I am on archlinux and the installed version (via package manager) for gnuradio and gnuradio-companion is 3.8.0.0-3.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a programming question, but more like a question about a bug in a software. You might want to look for some software-specific place (mailing list, forum, bugtracker, irc, discord...).

Comment: It seems you are right, but I thought there is some kind of error in what I am doing so I considered it to be some kind of programming question. I'll look for another place to ask.